# How to set assignment programmatically MS Project(Interop) using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-project

I am trying to create an MPP file (MS Project) using VB.NET in a windows forms application using the MS Project Interop.  I have been able to, create the project, load the resources and the tasks, but now I am stuck on how to assign the values for a resource to a task.  I need to set it at the month level.

[image]

Since the values can be different depending on the month, I cant figure out how to even begin.

The months and years could be different.  I need to be able to get the month/year and value and assign it to that task and resource.

Any ideas, because I do not know where to start.  Since you can zoom in and out in project to view it by day, week, month, qtr, year, it is confusing how to just set it by month.  Not sure if TimeScale has anything to do with it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.  There isnt much out there in terms of coding for MS Project like there is for excel or other office products.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create periodic assignments (e.g. day, week, month) you will need to use one of the TimeScaleData Methods (assignment, task, resource).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/f1/timescaledata-method-project-vbapj-chm131262?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbapj.chm131262)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

There is plenty of reference information about how to use Project's object model. I'm not sure how it might apply when using VB.net, but a good reference for Project VBA is available via the object browser.
[image]
John

Answer (score 1):

To set assignment work by month, use the [TimeScaleData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.assignment.timescaledata) method using the pjTimescaleMonths TimeScaleUnit parameter.

Here's a vba example of a helper routine that sets work for an assignment for a month:

```
Sub SetWorkForMonth(asn As Assignment, dteStart As Date, hours As Long)

    Dim dteEnd As Date
    dteEnd = DateAdd("m", 1, DateSerial(Year(dteStart), Month(dteStart), 1))
    
    Dim tsvs As TimeScaleValues

    Set tsvs = asn.TimeScaleData(StartDate:=dteStart, _
                                 EndDate:=dteEnd, _
                                 Type:=PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledWork, _
                                 TimeScaleUnit:=PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleMonths)
    tsvs(1).Value = hours * 60
    
End Sub
```

And here's sample code to demonstrate how it could be used:

```
Sub SampleAddAssignmentAndCustomTimeScale()

    Dim tsk As Task
    Set tsk = ActiveProject.Tasks.Add("LX21A...")
    tsk.Start = #8/10/2022#
    tsk.Duration = "120d"
    
    Dim asn As Assignment
    Set asn = tsk.Assignments.Add(, ActiveProject.Resources("Admin Functional Support 3").ID)
    SetWorkForMonth asn, #8/1/2022#, 10
    SetWorkForMonth asn, #9/1/2022#, 15
    SetWorkForMonth asn, #10/1/2022#, 15
    SetWorkForMonth asn, #11/1/2022#, 15
    SetWorkForMonth asn, #12/1/2022#, 10
    SetWorkForMonth asn, #1/1/2023#, 15
    SetWorkForMonth asn, #2/1/2023#, 20
    
End Sub
```

See also the [TimeScaleValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.timescalevalues) object which is a collection of [TimeScaleValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.timescalevalue) objects.

The example code will easily translate to vb.net

Comment: Also see [related SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-project%5Dtimescaledata).

Comment: Thank you.  I will give this a try.  Yea, there seems to be a lot for VBA, but not much for VB, but it easily translates.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Rachel, sorry, unrelated question, but insignficant to ask a new question.  How do i save the project out as an xml instead of an mpp.

Comment: Application.FileSaveAs "yourfilenamehere.xml", FormatID:="MSProject.xml". See [FileSaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.filesaveas).

Comment: So when i am setting the tsvs value, what am i entering there?  My data is in hours for the month.  So yes, in my example, it is 0.05 hours for the entire month.  My output is still showing 0.  What is the *60 for in your example

Comment: TimeScaleValues are entered in minutes. If you really need to enter fractional hours for an entire month, change the datatype in the SetWorkForMonth procedure to be: `hours As Double`.  But seriously, don't clog up your schedule with a resource assignment of only 3 minutes a month.

Comment: I got it to work thank you.  Quick question, how can i check if a task already exists without looping through them all.

Comment: ahhhh, so i set the task start and finish dates, set assignments with the work hours, but for the months that i do not put anything in, it autoload hours.  How do I stop it from doing that?

Comment: Example, one task is set from 3/2020 to 3/2023.  i am assigning a resource for 9/2022 to 3/2023.  My output project file is automatically putting in hours for 3/2020 to 8/2022, which i do not want.

Comment: Set the hours = 0 for those months.